# Can't load env variable path properly in crontab environment

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

If I ran manually on my terminal, working fine.

```
/usr/bin/python3 /home/myproject/handler.py
```

My command in crontab -e is

```
* * * * * . /home/<user>/.bashrc; /usr/bin/python3 /home/myproject/handler.py > /home/<user>/testfile.txt 2>&1
```

I got this error message in text file

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myproject/handler.py", line 9, in <module>
    env = json.load(open(os.environ.get('my_env_path'), encoding='utf-8'))
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

.bashrc

```
export my_env_path="/home/myproject/env.json"
```

It showing cant load successfully from bashrc file

Comment: Have you defined and exported the `my_env_path` environment variable in your `.bashrc` file?

Comment: yes, already setup

Comment: Can you update the post with the relevant content from `.bashrc`? Also, what is your default shell?

Comment: yes, its default shell. if I ran manually, no issue

Comment: `cron` will set the environment to *only* `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin`, `HOME=<home dir of user>`, `SHELL=/bin/sh`, and `LOGNAME=<user>`.  That's all.  What happens if you run `/bin/sh . /home/<user>/.bashrc; /usr/bin/python3 /home/myproject/handler.py` from a shell with **only** those environment variables set?

Comment: its working fine for this /bin/sh . /home/<user>/.bashrc; /usr/bin/python3 /home/myproject/handler.py but not in cron

Comment: I tried reproducing the problem with a similar setup as OP, and it runs without issues. Strange.